# Mysql taking more RAM space and gradually increasing without any drop down

Tags: java, mysql, performance, memory-management, memory-leaks

My application is written in Java. I'm using MySQL server for database. I found that mysqld.exe takes more memory space in Java. However it is gradually increasing without any drop down in memory. All my connections, preparedstatement and resultset are closed after its use. Why it takes a lot of memory? how to decrease the memory usage of mysqld.exe without reducing its performance?

Comment: I think you should put the code in which you access the database.

Comment: What does "I found that mysqld.exe takes more memory space in java." mean? Mysqld will use memory independently from java. You have to adjust your server options, e.g. disable performance_schema or lowering memory sizes for buffers, caches, .... But less memory generally means slower querys. There is very little you can do from java, except from maybe not using temporary tables, so mysql does not need to allocate that memory. Once used, mysqld does not give back memory, unless you restart it (what might be an option, if you use the server just for that application and have permission).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL and Java each use large chunks of RAM.

MySQL's main memory uses are

- InnoDB's cache.  It's size is controlled by `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, which typically should be set to about 70% of *available* RAM.  That is, after allowing space for Java.  The buffer_pool will grow until it reaches that limit, then this part of MySQL's memory will stop growing.
- Per-connection stuff.  This is controlled by quite a few settings.  The main things to note is to not randomly increase the many settings in `my.cnf`.  In particular, don't raise `max_connections` much.  (The current default is 151, which is arguably too high for most users.)  The per-connection stuff will come and go; but it is typically megabytes, not gigabytes.

If you need to discuss further, provide how much RAM you have, what the heap allotment for Java is, and `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`.